# How to insert `thead` component inside the `table` component?

Tags: angular, angular8

I am creating different `theads` with different values. for that i created a table component with just keeping `<table></table>` I am trying to insert the `thead` in to table. but not works.

what is the correct way to do it?

table component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './table.component.css' ]
})
export class TableComponent  {}
```

And thead component:

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-thead',
  templateUrl: './thead.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './thead.component.css' ]
})
export class TheadComponent  {}
```

html:

```
<thead>
    <th>Someple header</th>
    <th>Someple header</th>
</thead>
```

my try with app component:

```
<app-table>
  <app-thead></app-thead> //not getting anything.
</app-table>
```

Any one advice me the correct approach to handle this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must add <ng-content></ng-content> inside your table component Html

Comment: @ilyasshabi - where in the table component html file?

Comment: you can test with a blank table.component.html then add ng-content and check if this work for you

Comment: @ilyasshabi - yes it works. add as answer let me agree